# Using the deprecated AbsoluteLayout class in Android?

Tags: android, absolutelayout

The [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) class is deprecated but still can write it in code and it works. Will there be any problems if I use this class? Will the application work correctly after I deploy it on a phone?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you added a tag for the programming language and/or platform you're asking about.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539349/alternative-to-absolutelayout-in-android/14473541#14473541

This solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a piece of code is listed as deprecated, it means that it'll still work for the time being, but that in some future update of the code, support for it will be dropped.

This means you'll eventually have to come up with a different solution to the problem. Might as well do it now.

I do not recommend using deprecated functions if another function already exists that allows you to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Refer [Alternative to AbsoluteLayout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539349/alternative-to-absolutelayout-in-android/14473541#14473541)

This solves your problem..

Every deprecated method and class have the alternate solution.