# Using the deprecated AbsoluteLayout class in Android?

Tags: android, absolutelayout

The [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) class is deprecated but still can write it in code and it works. Will there be any problems if I use this class? Will the application work correctly after I deploy it on a phone?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you explain your problem, we can probably point you to the best (non-deprecated) layout to use.

Comment: Why did you repost this question?  It's an exact duplicate of a question you asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280060/deprecated-absolute-layout-options

Comment: I re-posted cause the tags were not clear

Comment: You could have just edited the tags of the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated generally means that you are discouraged from using it because better methods exist.  It can also serve as a warning that it will be removed entirely in future versions.

I would think you would want to stay away from absolute layouts because it can prevent your UI from scaling correctly on different resolutions, and it might not work at all on later versions of Android.

"will the application work correctly after I deploy it on a phone"  most likely yes, but like I said you are probably going to run into issues with phones having different display resolutions.

Comment: Thanks all
I was just wondering why the class is deprecated and still included in the sdk

Answer (score 1):

This is a mighty assumption. It depends on the purpose, a business application on a standard large-screen device (tablet) may have a reason to go absolute.

Comment: Well I believe it's true that you can use AbsoluteLayout only if your application is targeted at certain device, but again it may not appear correctly on different screen sizes

Comment: Only if "business application" is a synonym for "an awful user interface that looks like it was created in VB6"