# Adding swiping and rearranging to a recycle view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

Hello its been 2 days i am searching for a solution for this and still have no idea how to do, i want make a swipe left and right also rearrange recycle view,When user swipe left it will automatically list in completed list and if swipe on left it will delete list item in recycle view also user can rearrange the list element my long press.

Here is **main activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView shoppingItems;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private Realm realm;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    private List<ShoppingItem> dataSet;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter shoppingItemsAdapter = new RecyclerView.Adapter() {

        private final int ACTIVE_VIEW=1;
        private final int INACTIVE_VIEW=2;
        private final int SUBHEADER_VIEW=3;

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if(viewType == ACTIVE_VIEW) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.active_item, parent, false);
                return new ActiveItemViewHolder(v,
                        (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.item_status),
                        (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_name),
                        (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity),
                        (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_action)
                        );
            } else if(viewType == INACTIVE_VIEW) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inactive_item, parent, false);
                return new InactiveItemViewHolder(v,
                        (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.item_status),
                        (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_name),
                        (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_action)
                );
            } else {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.subheader, parent, false);
                return new SubheaderViewHolder(v);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final ShoppingItem currentItem = dataSet.get(position);
            if(currentItem.getTimestamp()==-1) return;
            if(currentItem.isCompleted()) {
                InactiveItemViewHolder h = (InactiveItemViewHolder)holder;
                h.itemName.setText(currentItem.getName());
                h.itemName.setPaintFlags(h.itemName.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                h.itemAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Task is restored", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                        snackbar.show();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        currentItem.setCompleted(false);
                        currentItem.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        initializeDataSet();
                        shoppingItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                ActiveItemViewHolder h = (ActiveItemViewHolder)holder;
                h.itemName.setText(currentItem.getName());
                h.itemQuantity.setText(currentItem.getQuantity());
                h.itemStatus.setChecked(false);
                h.itemStatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                        if (checked) {
                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            currentItem.setCompleted(true);
                            currentItem.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                            realm.commitTransaction();
                            initializeDataSet();
                            shoppingItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Task is Completed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            realm.beginTransaction();
                                            currentItem.setCompleted(false);
                                            currentItem.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                                            realm.commitTransaction();
                                            initializeDataSet();
                                            shoppingItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Task is restored!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                            snackbar1.show();
                                        }
                                    });

                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                h.itemAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("TITLE", "Edit item");
                        i.putExtra("ITEM_NAME", currentItem.getName());
                        i.putExtra("ITEM_QUANTITY", currentItem.getQuantity());
                        i.putExtra("ITEM_ID", currentItem.getId());
                        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dataSet.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            ShoppingItem currentItem = dataSet.get(position);
            if(currentItem.getTimestamp()==-1) return SUBHEADER_VIEW;
            if(currentItem.isCompleted()) return INACTIVE_VIEW;
            return ACTIVE_VIEW;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RealmConfiguration configuration =
                new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("TITLE", "Add Task");
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });

        shoppingItems = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.shopping_items);
        shoppingItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        initializeDataSet();
        shoppingItems.setAdapter(shoppingItemsAdapter);
    }

    private void initializeDataSet() {
        dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        RealmResults<ShoppingItem> activeItemResults
                = realm.where(ShoppingItem.class).equalTo("completed", false)
                .findAllSorted("timestamp", Sort.DESCENDING);
        RealmResults<ShoppingItem> inactiveItemResults
                = realm.where(ShoppingItem.class).equalTo("completed", true)
                .findAllSorted("timestamp", Sort.DESCENDING);

        ShoppingItem subheader = new ShoppingItem();
        subheader.setTimestamp(-1);

        for(ShoppingItem item:activeItemResults) dataSet.add(item);
        dataSet.add(subheader);
        for(ShoppingItem item:inactiveItemResults) dataSet.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            initializeDataSet();
            shoppingItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

**activity main.xml**

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="com.github.hathibelagal.shoppinglist.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**active_item.xml:**

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="72dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_status"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/item_quantity" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_action"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_24dp"
        android:alpha="0.26" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me! Thanks for advance!

Comment: Have a look at : https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Comment: Can you provide code for my situation? i was trying everything but still not working on my code :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.lrbbupqkq

Stack Overflow post for the same :

[RecyclerView Swipe with a view below it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227482/recyclerview-swipe-with-a-view-below-it)

[Drag and drop items in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901044/drag-and-drop-items-in-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager)

Comment: yeah i was trying the itemtouchhelper but it showing me error and was trying the code whole day.. can you please provide code? i really need help :(