# Android how to make ListView swipe menu on icon handle

Tags: android, listview, swipe

Hi I want to make my ListView when swipe left to show more menu.

I googled and found this library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout  .

**but I want to use only with handle icon.** It means only swipe on that icon to activate  and show menu.
Because I use PagerView for tabs, so when swipe on the rest area it will change tab.

Can anyone guide me how to do it?
Or any Library is fine.

Comment: You could try to overwrite the onTouchListener of the icon to catch the swipe and anything else doesn't respond to the swipe event.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use `RecycleView` with `ItemTouchHelper`

Here is similar question with answer [RecyclerView Swipe with a view below it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227482/recyclerview-swipe-with-a-view-below-it)