# how to fix the width of swiping in ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback swipe method in android

Tags: android, swipe

I am trying to delete the recyclerview item. once user swipes the item it should move for particular width not completely so that i can add a button in that swiped portion allowing user to click on that to delete the item.Exactly like the image attached. At the place of settings icon i want to show my own image when item is swiped.

[image: recylerview item swipe with fixed width]

Answer (score 1):

This is not intended to behave that way. But its possible. Firstly (Recommended) there are some 3rd party librarys that will help you. Here is one of them:

[advanced-Recyclerview on Github](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

Alternatively if you want to go the more complicated way but not 3rd party dependent way check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204874/showing-custom-view-under-swiped-recyclerview-item).