# Android - Swipe to delete RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement swipe to delete the same as Gmail app "Swipe to archive":

[image: gmail swipe delete]
[image: gmail swipe delete]

I have tried many tutorials but none of them works as fast as gmail, 
I prefer to not work on external library. How can i do it?

***Edit:***

My code so far-

```
  ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
//                    final int fromPos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
//                    final int toPos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
//                    // move item in `fromPos` to `toPos` in adapter.
                    return true;// true if moved, false otherwise
                }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

I've managed to enable swipe gesture but **i don't know how to add a background and an image under the viewHolder**. I tried to put another FrameLayout at the item_XXX.xml file but on swipe it throws the whole item with the background.

Comment: This will help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293960/swipe-to-dismiss-for-recyclerview

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820806/adding-a-colored-background-with-text-icon-under-swiped-row-when-using-androids, there is a solution using overriding onChildDraw.

Comment: am looking for longpresson item populate contextual action mode with delete option android please help me

Comment: how can i implement like gmail single and multiselection with cab popup for menu items remove share

Comment: I strongly recommended to look at this tutorial: https://medium.com/@kitek/recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-easier-than-you-thought-cff67ff5e5f6

Comment: See https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Simple Code for RecyclerView Swipe:**

```
     ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP) {

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "on Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "on Swiped ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                arrayList.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
     };
```

Then set callback for recyclerView with below statements:

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
 itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);
```

Comment: For a smother animation you can use 'adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)' instead of 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();'

Comment: @LMiranda Im having a problem with notifyItemRemoved(position): when I call it, the item that I swiped is removed, however another element is drawn in the list, and inside the adaptar the size of the list hasn't actually changed, even though I did remove the element. In example, if I have 3 elements and I remove one, the getItemCount in the adapter still returns 3 and then redraws one of the items again, any clue as to why it's happening?

Comment: you'll need to remove the item from list inside the adapter also. remove the item from list then use adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) and 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to make it work

Answer (score 32):

I had to do this the other day and I had some issues so I decided to write a blog post on it. No 3rd party lib necessary.

- [Blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-no-3rd-party-lib-necessary-6bf6a6601214)
- [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete)

Basically, you wouldn't draw the "undo state" via `onChildDraw`, it would be done via `ViewHolder`. Also you wouldn't actually delete row in `onSwipe` just mark it as "pending delete" and notify adapter to rebind it in "undo state". At the same time you post a `Runnable` actually removing the row in x seconds unless undo button is pressed...

Comment: Nice implementation even I was trying something similar to that I was able to achieve swipe in both the directions [Partial Swipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747458/partial-and-full-swipe-for-recyclerview-using-touchhelpercallback) but can we achieve a partial swipe, just to let user know they can do the same operation with partial swipe ?

Comment: Is it possible to do this onclick instead of onswipe?

Comment: gmail single and multiselection recyclerview longpress contextual action mode popup for delete ad share

Comment: I have implemented your code, how Do I add onClickListener to `delete` icon

Comment: @rookieDeveloper try this !! https://github.com/ashrithks/SwipeRecyclerView , u can customize the view on swiped.

Comment: You can get help form this tutorial http://www.sunilandroid.com/2016/12/swipe-to-delete-item-of-recyclerview-in.html

Comment: I cannot seem to view your blog post anymore @nemanja . Did you remove it?

Comment: Hi @kjanderson2 it should be accessible again, I had some issues with the website...

Answer (score 8):

Here's the minimum code in your `onCreate` that sets up "Swipe Left to Delete":

```
binding.rows.adapter = adapter
ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    override fun onMove(v: RecyclerView, h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, t: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = false
    override fun onSwiped(h: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dir: Int) = adapter.removeAt(h.adapterPosition)
}).attachToRecyclerView(binding.rows)
```

This assumes your `Adapter` class has a `removeAt` function. Mine looks like this:

```
fun removeAt(index: Int) {
    items.removeAt(index)   // items is a MutableList
    notifyItemRemoved(index)
}
```

Thanks @RahulRaina for your Java answer!

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Swipeable-RecyclerView](https://github.com/tsuryo/Swipeable-RecyclerView)

```
    SwipeableRecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    rv.setListener(new SwipeLeftRightCallback.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipedLeft(int position) {
            mList.remove(position);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedRight(int position) {
            mList.remove(position);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

xml for two sides swipe

```
<com.tsuryo.swipeablerv.SwipeableRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:leftBgColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:leftImage="@drawable/ic_remove"
    app:leftText="Delete"
    app:rightBgColor="@color/blue"
    app:rightImage="@drawable/ic_check"
    app:rightText="Read"
    app:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:textSize="20sp" />
```