# Partial and full swipe for Recyclerview using TouchHelperCallback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve partial and full swipe for Recyclerview using the api TouchHelperCallback,came acrosscouple of libraries like https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout and https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo but how can achieve this using the api ?

I was able to achieve full swipe with the below code,can anyone please give a suggestion on how to approach this problem.

Thanks

Code base:

ExtendItemTouchHelperCallback:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;


public abstract class ExtendItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback
{

    private int mCachedMaxScrollSpeed = -1; // default
    private static final long DRAG_SCROLL_ACCELERATION_LIMIT_TIME_MS = 2000; // default

    @Override
    public abstract int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);

    @Override
    public abstract boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1);

    @Override
    public abstract void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i);


    @Override
    public abstract void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);

    @Override
    public abstract void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState);

    @Override
    public abstract void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive);

    @Override
    public abstract void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive);


    // default
    @Override
    public int interpolateOutOfBoundsScroll(RecyclerView recyclerView, int viewSize, int viewSizeOutOfBounds, int totalSize, long msSinceStartScroll)
    {
//        return super.interpolateOutOfBoundsScroll(recyclerView, viewSize, viewSizeOutOfBounds, totalSize, msSinceStartScroll);
        final int maxScroll = Util.getMaxDragScroll(recyclerView);
        final int absOutOfBounds = Math.abs(viewSizeOutOfBounds);
        final int direction = (int) Math.signum(viewSizeOutOfBounds);
        // might be negative if other direction
        float outOfBoundsRatio = Math.min(1f, 1f * absOutOfBounds / viewSize);
        final int cappedScroll = (int) (direction * maxScroll *
                Util.sDragViewScrollCapInterpolator.getInterpolation(outOfBoundsRatio));
        final float timeRatio;
        if (msSinceStartScroll > DRAG_SCROLL_ACCELERATION_LIMIT_TIME_MS)
        {
            timeRatio = 1f;
//            timeRatio = 3f;
        }
        else
        {
            timeRatio = (float) msSinceStartScroll / DRAG_SCROLL_ACCELERATION_LIMIT_TIME_MS;
        }
        final int value = (int) (cappedScroll * Util.sDragScrollInterpolator.getInterpolation(timeRatio));
        if (value == 0)
        {
            return viewSizeOutOfBounds > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return value;
    }


}
```

Util:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class Util
{
    private static int mCachedMaxScrollSpeed = -1; // default
    private static final long DRAG_SCROLL_ACCELERATION_LIMIT_TIME_MS = 2000; // default

    // default
    public static int getMaxDragScroll(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        if (mCachedMaxScrollSpeed == -1)
        {
            mCachedMaxScrollSpeed = recyclerView.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.support.v7.recyclerview.R.dimen.item_touch_helper_max_drag_scroll_per_frame);
        }
        return mCachedMaxScrollSpeed;
    }

    // default
    public static final Interpolator sDragScrollInterpolator = new Interpolator()
    {
        public float getInterpolation(float t)
        {
//            return t * t * t * t * t; // default return value, but it's too late for me
            return (int) Math.pow(2, (double) t); // optional whatever you like        }
        }

    };

    // default
    public static final Interpolator sDragViewScrollCapInterpolator = new Interpolator()
    {
        public float getInterpolation(float t)
        {
            t -= 1.0f;
            return t * t * t * t * t + 10.0f;
        }
    };

}
```

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_facade_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_main_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_sub_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sub text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_rear_right_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <Button
            android:id="@android:id/button1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_rear_left_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <Button
            android:id="@android:id/button1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_remove"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and implementing the callback in activity

```
private ItemTouchHelper.Callback crateCallback()
    {
        return new ExtendItemTouchHelperCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
            {

                if (viewHolder instanceof ItemAdapter.ViewHolder)
                {

                    //this make sure that the value works for the drag and drop too
                    //return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) | makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG, ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN);
                    return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);

                }
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
            {
                final int fromPos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                final int toPos = target.getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, " postion " + "From: " + fromPos + " TO: " + toPos);
                mItemAdapter.move(fromPos, toPos);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
            {
                int removedId = mItemAdapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

               // Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, "Item removed, position: " + removedId, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                //ExtendAsyncQueryHandler extendAsyncQueryHandler = new ExtendAsyncQueryHandler(getActivity().getContentResolver());
                //extendAsyncQueryHandler.startDelete(removedId, null, DataContract.ItemEntry.buildItemUri(removedId), null, null);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "removed row; " + removedId);
            }

            @Override
            public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
            {
                getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).mFacadeLayout);
//                getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView);//                ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).setLayoutVisibility(false);
                ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).setLayoutVisibility(ItemAdapter.SWIPE_END);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState)
            {
                if (viewHolder != null) {
                    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).mFacadeLayout);
//                        ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).setLayoutVisibility(true);
                    } else if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {

                        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView);
                    } else {
                        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView);
                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive)
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dx: " + dX + " dy: " + dY);



                if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

                    float swipingDx = dX;
                    String swipingDirection;
                    if (swipingDx > 0) {
                        swipingDirection = ItemAdapter.SWIPING_RIGHT;
                    } else if (swipingDx < 0) {
                        swipingDirection = ItemAdapter.SWIPING_LEFT;
                    } else {
                        swipingDirection = ItemAdapter.SWIPE_END;
                    }
//                    String swipingDirection = swipingDx > 0 ? ItemAdapter.SWIPING_RIGHT :ItemAdapter.SWIPING_LEFT;

                    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView,
                            ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).mFacadeLayout, dX, dY,
                            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                    ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).setLayoutVisibility(swipingDirection);

                } else {
                    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView,
                            ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView, dX, dY,
                            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive)
            {
                if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView,
                            ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).mFacadeLayout, dX, dY,
                            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                } else {
                    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView,
                            ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView, dX, dY,
                            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
//                    ((ItemAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).setLayoutVisibility(false);                }
                }


            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: comment - not a good soluction i guess - in onChildDraw and onChildDrawOver, just divide by 2 the dX, and it will only drag half the way

Comment: Did you achieve it with a partial swipe? with "Partial" I mean as much space as the view that is coming from left to right or from right to left..

Comment: Hello, I followed your example, I also was successful to have partial swipe controlled by the user (extremely difficult and not working well), but in the end, I abandoned because clicks on rear views are impossible to manage (also when it is fully swiped): it closes the FrontView without reasons. So I deleted my code, but it is in my Github page on a specific commit.

Also useful to mention is that the dX we receive is the full dragAmount of the itemView (all the time!), so if we change translationX for the front view it works if you open, but when you closes it starts from max dX (width).

Comment: https://github.com/Mohammad-Taqi/Swipe-RecycleView-Item

perhaps this is useful to you.