# Swipe right to open another activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity where there are `ImageView`s as items in a `ScrolView`, this list will grow as time goes. What I want to do is when I swipe right on an item (imageView) it should navigate to another activity (let's say, `orderActivity`) where I can take further action. TextViews on `orderActivity` to be populated (details like, name of the item, price, quantity, etc) based on the item that is swiped right.

Following is the XML code, I don't have any idea how to code for the swipe right.

Is this the way it should be done, or is there a better way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListOfItems">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="6dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iVitemOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/item1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iVitemTwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iVitemOne"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/item2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iVitemThree"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iVitemTwo"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/item3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iVitemFour"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iVitemThree"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/item4" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am on Android Studio using Kotlin.

Edit:

I added the Override part into the ListOfItems.kt file as follows. I know it's wrong.

```
class ListOfGames : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_games)
    }

    imageview.setOnTouchListener(object :OnSwipeTouchListener(context){
        override fun onSwipeRight() {
            //Do want you want
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: you have the idea of how to detect swipe or you don't?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: you'll try this hope it'll help you :https://stackoverflow.com/a/40374244

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class (Kotlin version of another answer in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/4390987))

```
 open class OnSwipeTouchListener(ctx: Context?) : OnTouchListener {
    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector  = GestureDetector(ctx, GestureListener())

    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
        private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100

        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
            var result = false
            try {
                val diffY: Float = e2.y - e1.y
                val diffX: Float = e2.x - e1.x
                if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY)) {
                    if (abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight()
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft()
                        }
                        result = true
                    }
                } else if (abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom()
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop()
                    }
                    result = true
                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
            return result
        }
    }

    open fun onSwipeRight() {}
    open fun onSwipeLeft() {}
    open fun onSwipeTop() {}
    open fun onSwipeBottom() {}
}
```

and use it with your `ImageView`s like

```
iVitemOne.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(requireContext()){
            override fun onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight()

            }

            override fun onSwipeLeft() {
                super.onSwipeLeft()
            }
        })
```

Comment: What needs to be at requireContext?

Comment: @user3765415 It just returns context from a fragment. If you are using Activity then you need to use `youractivityName.this`

Comment: Error
ListOfGames.kt file.

`class ListOfGames : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_games)
        val iVitemOne=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iVFIFA20)
        iVitemOne.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this()){
            override fun onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight()
            }
            override fun onSwipeLeft() {
                super.onSwipeLeft()
            }
        })
    }
}`

Comment: you need to pass `this` instead of `MainActivity.this()` inside `OnSwipeTouchListener()`

Comment: That fixed the error but nothing happens when I swipe right or left on the ImageView, iVFIFA20.

There is a grey squiggly line that says "Custom view 'ImageView' has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick. 
Issue id: ClickableViewAccesibility.

Comment: It is working for me. Try adjusting `SWIPE_THRESHOLD ` value and see what fits for your need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205289/discussion-between-user3765415-and-somesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Create `OnSwipeTouchListener` which is drived from `View.OnTouchListener`.This class help you to listern the `left`,`right`,`top` and `bottom` swipe.

```
class OnSwipeTouchListener(ctx: Context?) : OnTouchListener {
private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}

private inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    private  val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
    private  val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100
    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        var result = false
        try {
            val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
            val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(
                        velocityX
                    ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
                ) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight()
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft()
                    }
                    result = true
                }
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(
                    velocityY
                ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
            ) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom()
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop()
                }
                result = true
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
        return result
    } 
}

fun onSwipeRight() {}
fun onSwipeLeft() {}
fun onSwipeTop() {}
fun onSwipeBottom() {}

init {
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(ctx, GestureListener())
}
}
```

Now you need to `override` this methods for your view.

```
  imageview.setOnTouchListener(object :OnSwipeTouchListener(context){
    override fun onSwipeRight() {
       //Do want you want
    }
})
```

That's it. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I think this is JAVA code, I am using Kotlin as mentioned in my question.

Comment: then you can covert that in kotlin not bigdeal.

Comment: I am just a beginner, I might do things incorrectly.

What I did now is that I created a new class file with a name 'OnSwipeTouchListener' and added the first block of code into it and converted the code into Kotlin.
Now I am left with a few errors.

I do not know where and how to add the Override part, the second set of codes.

Comment: Updated code has no build errors, bravo. But I am still not able to use the code as I don't know how to use the second part, 'override'.

I tried, but I do know if that is the right way to do it and I got errors. Can you tell me how to do the second part?

Comment: I added the Override part into the ListOfItems.kt file as follows. I know it's wrong.

class ListOfGames : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_games)
    }

    imageview.setOnTouchListener(object :OnSwipeTouchListener(context){
        override fun onSwipeRight() {
            //Do want you want
        }
    })

}

Comment: Update your question  don't add as comment bcoz it is not understandable. And if it is not working for `recyclerview` then try this for any individual like `imageview` or `textview`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205227/discussion-between-user3765415-and-frankenstein).