# Android Swipe List Item with animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, swipe

I have a recycler view with implemented swipe left/right option. My animation is here:

res/anim/slide_left_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="0%"     android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="1.0"     android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

and it works good, but I want to change its color when swiping start (as Gmail inbox). View.setBackground(...) does not work.

How I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: use the external library  for this it will help to solve the issue

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820806/adding-a-colored-background-with-text-icon-under-swiped-row-when-using-androids

Comment: No, it isn't solution, I have custom recyclerView and want to import change color on swipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these external libraries

[SwipeListView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4144)

[SwipeMenuListView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/912)