# Positioning a TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView`. How can I position it by using x and y coordinates?

```
TextView leftArrow = new TextView(this);
    leftArrow.setTypeface(tf);
    leftArrow.setText("<");
    leftArrow.setTextSize(30);
    ll.addView(leftArrow);
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? position the textview where ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use view.setX() and view.setY() ,see the following link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)

Comment: You could also use view.setLeft(int left) and view.setTop(int top), setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom), or view.setLayoutParams() (with margin settings for the layout parameters).

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want x,y positioning, use the deprecated [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) -- but read [Alternative to AbsoluteLayout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539349/alternative-to-absolutelayout-in-android) before (it's no good for different screen sizes).

You'll likely fare much better with [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) depending on your problem.